# Space for messages in figure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Inside figure(1), I have a plot with label axis, title, legend etc and under this plot, still inside figure(1), I want to add a space where I can display few lines that right now I'm showing inside the command windows.

Like this:

[image: desired output]

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about exploiting [`subplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)?

```
subplot(10,1,1:7);                     %Taking most of the figure space for actual plot
plot(randperm(100),'d-');              %A random plot
xlabel('xlabel');  ylabel('ylabel');   %Axis Labels
legend show;                           %Legend display

subplot(10,1,10);                      %And just one part for the text/messages
xlim([1 10]);                          %For aesthetics
str = {'Comment-1','Comment-2'};       %Text that we want to display
text(1,1,str);                         %Putting the text
axis off;                              %Turning off the axis
```

[image: output]

Comment: I already tried this way, the problem is what I want to print is not a static text but a variable. I tried using`str = {'Text' num2str(variable)}; ` and even if works, it puts the number in a new line like it was another string, while I want "text and variable" in the same line.

Comment: @Shika93 It should have been `str = {['Text' num2str(variable)]};` (notice the brackets.

Comment: There's the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Shika93 btw you don't need any `{ }` in above if you have just one line. `str = ['Text' num2str(variable)];` is okay for one line. If your have multiple lines, it would be `str = {['Text' num2str(variable1)] , ['Text' num2str(variable2)]};`

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I've done. I have multiple lines indeed.